# How to reduce the amount of aggreation queries with mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am having a hard time to come up with the right title for this question (open to suggestions)

I am developing a statistics page that compares various input against each others.

For instance I have a query that calculates an age distribution against the gender of a personn.

```
{
  $bucket: {
    groupBy : "$age",
    boundaries:[12,13,14,15,16,17],
    default:"other",
    output : {
      "male" : {$sum : {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$gender", "male" ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}},
      "female" : {$sum : {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$gender", "female" ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example I only wanted the ages from 12 to 17.

This is an example of the resulted output:

```
[
{
"_id": 12,
"male": 0,
"female": 1
},
{
"_id": 14,
"male": 0,
"female": 1
},
{
"_id": 15,
"male": 1,
"female": 0
},
{
"_id": 16,
"male": 2,
"female": 0
},
{
"_id": "other",
"male": 1,
"female": 0
}
]
```

When I will iterate through this query my rows will be the gender and the columns the age.

But what if I want to iterate in oposite / reverse manner (rows would be the age and the columns the gender)

1. It's a manipulation I can do client side by some magic iteration tricks
2. I have to build a separate aggregation query for the case also
3. My query is wrongly designed and I can have one that would allow me to easily switch row / columns fields

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Your question is open, so my comment is also: Have a look at [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html), this you can use for your transformation

Comment: Okay thanks I am going to think about how can this help in my case, in the meantime I edited the question to add a result output sample for clarity.

Comment: Show us also the desired output.

Comment: The result of my current query is already the desired output. I am just having a hard time wrapping my head around how to iterate through it in the two possible ways. With the current result I can iterate in the following manner: my rows are the age and the columns the gender. But what if I want the gender to be the rows and the columns the age. I don't know if it makes sense